How can I write a Linq query that returns rows that are in a specific period of dates?
I am using EF Core 7 and C#. In the model, one Employee has many Periods and many Tickets.
I have the following classes:
public class Employee
{    
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }    
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public List<Period> Periods { get; set; }
    public List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}

public class Period
{
    public int PeriodId { get; set; }  
    
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
    
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; } //FK pointing to Employee
}

public class Ticket
{ 
    public string TicketId { get; set; }        
    
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
   
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; } //FK pointing to Employee
}

How can I write a linq query that returns the tickets that are in
the range of period of the employees? I need the result as a IQueryable<Ticket>.
Here is the query I was trying:
// I create a list of employees Id's
var employeeIds = new List<string> { "9854", "4587", "2587" };

IQueryable<Ticket> result =
     from ticket in DbContext.Tickets
     where employeeIds.Contains(ticket.EmployeeId) &&
     
           // Here I need to set the condition for tickets
           // that are inside the Period of each employee
           // [Period.From , Period.To] 
     
     select ticket;
}


(1) Are your ticket CreationDate values plain old dates or date/times?  (2) Are the period To date values inclusive dates (00:00 on the last included day) or exclusive dates (00:00 on the day after the last included day)? -- This makes a big difference in how you need to compare dates to date ranges.

Really great to see someone remembers to put csharp class definition in their question!

This should be what you want:
IQueryable<Ticket> result = 
     from ticket in DbContext.Tickets
      where employeeIds.Contains(ticket.EmployeeId)  
        && DbContext.Periods.Any(p => p.EmployeeId == ticket.EmployeeId 
            && ticket.CreationDate >= p.From && ticket.CreationDate <= p.To)
    select ticket;

So i check if there is at least one period for each ticket-employee which from/to are in the ticket's CreationDate range.

If you are OK with result being IEnumerable<Ticket> instead of IQueryable<Ticket>, you can also perform a join on employeeIds, tickets, periods on EmployeeId. and then filter tickets based on periods To/From date.
    //I create a list of employees Id's
    var employeeIds = new List<string> {"9854", "4587", "2587"};
    var tickets = new List<Ticket>
    {
        new Ticket {TicketId = "ticketId1", EmployeeId = "9854", CreationDate = new DateTime(2021, 9, 20)},
        new Ticket {TicketId = "ticketId2", EmployeeId = "9854", CreationDate = new DateTime(2021, 10, 20)},
        new Ticket {TicketId = "ticketId3", EmployeeId = "9855", CreationDate = new DateTime(2021, 9, 20)},
    };

    var periods = new List<Period>
    {
        new Period {PeriodId = 1, EmployeeId = "9854", From = new DateTime(2021, 8, 20), To = new DateTime(2021, 9, 21)},
        new Period {PeriodId = 2, EmployeeId = "9854", From = new DateTime(2021, 10, 18), To = new DateTime(2021, 10, 21)},
    };

    var results = (from employeedId in employeeIds
        join period in periods on employeedId equals period.EmployeeId into employeePeriods
        join ticket in tickets on employeedId equals ticket.EmployeeId into employeeTickets
        where employeeTickets.Count() > 0 && employeePeriods.Count() > 0
        select new {employeePeriods, employeeTickets}).SelectMany(q =>
    {
        var employeeTickets = q.employeeTickets;
        var employeePeriods = q.employeePeriods;
        var ticketsWithinPeriod = employeeTickets.Where(t => employeePeriods.Any(p => p.From <= t.CreationDate && p.To >= t.CreationDate));
        return ticketsWithinPeriod;
    });

Results:

